# Uploading profile image with twitter api and python

Tags: python, api, twitter

I want to upload an image from my hard drive, using an html form:

```
Image file: <input name="imageupload" id="imageupload" type="file" />
```

Then I upload it to twitter with:

```
image=self.request.get('imageupload')
image2=base64.b64encode(image)
twitapi.Update_profile_image(image=image2)
```

given twitapi.Update_profile_image:

```
def Update_profile_image(self,image):
    if not self._oauth_consumer:
        raise TwitterError("The twitter.Api instance must be authenticated.")

    url = '%s/account/update_profile_image.json' % (self.base_url)
    data = {'image':image}

    json = self._FetchUrl(url, post_data=data)
    data = self._ParseAndCheckTwitter(json)
    return data
```

Given _FetchUrl from twitter-api

I always get

```
TwitterError: There was a problem with your picture. Probably too big.
```

Any ideas whee it comes from? Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified the success of each step along the way? 

Is the image uploading correctly? Is self.request.get('imageupload') getting the file? Can you display the image elsewhere after encoding (try http://jsfiddle.net/hpP45/ )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To submit ah image correctly via a form, you have to include

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

eg

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" action='/' method="POST">
```

Answer (score 2):

`Twitter RESTful API Document` is not correct.
Do NOT **encode** `image binary` to `base64`!
Remove `base64` encode section from your source.

If you encode `image binary` to `base64` string, `twitter` api says

> "... was a problem with your picture probably too big. (...) (code 131)"

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/account/update_profile_image), your image:

```
Must be a valid GIF, JPG, or PNG image of less than 700 kilobytes in size.
```

So make sure your image fits within these constraints. Maybe you need to scale down your image, or convert it to a different format.

If that doesn't work, try uploading another very tiny image that meets the constraints above. At least you can then verify whether or not the problem lays with the particular image you are using.

Comment: I got them same problem with several images, that all fit the constraints.
Problem is in the encoding of the image

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the image you are receiving via the form upload is already base64 encoded ?

You are then applying a double encoding which could confuse the validation on the twitter server side because it would be unable to find a typical image header in your uploaded file.

Comment: Actually the error happens both with and without encoding the image.